# Browser tab text file encoding on Web application

Tags: internet-explorer, character-encoding, vaadin, wildfly

I'm running a web-application, made with Vaadin Framework in JBoss WildFly.
The encoding is UTF-8 on all the pages.

However, there are links to files on my application on one view. Just normal file links that open a file in a Browser. Now, if those files happen to be txt-files, they are opened to a new tab. UNICODE-characters don't show correctly in one environment and they work perfectly in another environment. The application version is exactly the same, so it shouldn't be programmatical.

In the environment where UNICODE (letters like ä ö å) are showing correctly the browswer switches the encoding to "Western European (Windows)" in the opened tab.

In the environment where UNICODE does NOT work, the encoding stays as UTF-8 even when opening a text file and the ä, ö and å letters only show as white boxes.

The NOT working browser also shows the characters correctly, when I just open the txt-file with the browser and not through the web application.

I checked the standalone.xml in both WildFlys and they have no differences in regards to encoding.

The code is of course identical since it is the exactly same version from the repository. Both are using Internet Explorer 11.

How to determine what encoding is used in these cases? Are there some settings in WildFly on top of standalone.xml that could affect this? I'm clueless at this point.

Comment: How are the text files delivered? If not by wildfly, then the http Server sends another encoding

Comment: Tools>Internet Options>General tab, under the Accessibility and Language settings there are options to choose the default font and text font for the current browser language setting. Ensure that View>Encoding has Unicode (UTF-8) selected also.